# Link between MongoDB Casbah and Logback

Tags: mongodb, scala, logging, logback, casbah

I have a sbt project, and I work with MongoDB (Driver Casbah).

I want to have logs on my application, so I tried to use Logback Framework.
It works but I don't understand exactly what my code is doing..

here is my code for logs :

```
def logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Test log")
StatusPrinter.print(LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory.asInstanceOf[LoggerContext])
logger.info("Azuken")
```

and here is my logs :

```
14:36:16.616 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Registering Scala Conversions.
14:36:16.633 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Deserializers for Scala Conversions registering
14:36:16.641 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Serializers for Scala Conversions registering
14:36:16.647 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Setting up OptionSerializer
14:36:16.658 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Setting up ScalaCollectionSerializer
14:36:16.669 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Setting up ScalaRegexSerializers
14:36:16.677 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Hooking up scala.util.matching.Regex serializer
14:36:16.683 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Reached base registration method on MongoConversionHelper.
14:36:17.056 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Registering Scala Conversions.
14:36:17.059 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Deserializers for Scala Conversions registering
14:36:17.063 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Serializers for Scala Conversions registering
14:36:17.067 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Setting up OptionSerializer
14:36:17.071 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Setting up ScalaCollectionSerializer
14:36:17.079 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Setting up ScalaRegexSerializers
14:36:17.083 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Hooking up scala.util.matching.Regex serializer
14:36:17.087 [run-main] DEBUG c.m.c.c.c.s.RegisterConversionHelpers$ - Reached base registration method on MongoConversionHelper.
```

I've seen that is MongoDB actions, but I don't understand which line of my code do what...

Any explanations ? I've searched on the web but I've not found a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Theres lots of debug logging in Casbah, the logging you are seeing are the automatic handling that ensures scala types are handled and registered for BSON encoding / decoding.

Comment: Okay, but why it's still displayed while I comment my code ? Before I had no log messages from MongoDB

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  Or provide a full example so I can replicate?

Comment: First I haven't used logs in my application, so when I executed my program, no logs were displayed. But since I implemented Logback code, it show me logs in the console, even if I delete Logback code ; do you know what I mean ?